# Remove newline from awk

Tags: unix, awk, csh

I use awk for print file line by line. I need to remove every newline character using awk.

My code

```
while($lines>0)
    echo -n "Output: '"
    awk NR==$i output.txt
    echo "'"
    @ i++
    @ lines--
end
```

Output must be like this:
Output: 'something'

Maybe I need better solution

My file looks like this:
name1 10
name2 12
name3 5

My output must be:
Output: 'name1 10'
Output: 'name2 12'
Output: 'name3 5'

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Please post sample data with the related expected output.

Comment: I need to have output like this: Output 'line from file'

Comment: Do you want something like `tr -d '\n'< file` ?

Comment: Sorry, but your code (and example data) make no sense. Based on you headline, just try `awk -v OFS=" " {print $0}' file`. Good luck.

Comment: This should work for all inputs: `awk 'BEGIN{print "Output \047line from file\047"; exit}'`. Good luck.

Comment: @JamesBrown how to add line from file?

Comment: @JamesBrown awk 'BEGIN{print "Output \047NR==$i\047"; exit}' prints **Output 'NR==$i'**

Comment: your sample output is now further confusing the issue. Per your headline "Remove newline". your sample output has newlines in it. Also, do you really want it to include the word "Output:" ? AND do you really want the text from the file enclosed in single quotes (as shown in your example). Don't reply in comments, fix you Title Q and your sample input and output to be exactly what you are trying to solve. Good luck.

Comment: You might also want to clarify if you really need to use a shell looping construct to process your data. To produce your current sample output all that is needed is `awk '{print "Output: "'"'"'$0'"'"'}' file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

... answering to example provided.

myfile:

```
$ cat myfile
name1 10
name2 12
name3 5
```

awk:

```
$ awk '{ print("Output: \047" $0 "\047"); }' myfile
Output: 'name1 10'
Output: 'name2 12'
Output: 'name3 5'
```

sed:

```
$ sed "s/.*/Output: '&'/" myfile
Output: 'name1 10'
Output: 'name2 12'
Output: 'name3 5'
```

bash:

```
$ while read -r LINE; do echo "Output: '${LINE}'"; done < myfile
Output: 'name1 10'
Output: 'name2 12'
Output: 'name3 5'
```